# How do I get local server running - here with language error message?

Tags: python, django, ssl-certificate

I have a Django app (with a postgres database) running in a virtual environment. Everything has been working on my localhost until a few days ago when I got an error saying my SSL certificate had expired (localhost:8000). Today, when I tried the python manage.py runserver command I got an error saying psycopg2 was not installed. I know it was because I have been using this app for the last nine months! Anyway, I reinstalled psycopg2 and tried the runserver command again.  This time I got the following error message:

$ python manage.py runserver

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 90, in <module>
    class Group(models.Model):
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 161, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1637, in contribute_to_class
    self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1099, in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    'verbose_name': _('%(from)s-%(to)s relationship') % {'from': from_, 'to': to},
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 176, in __mod__
    return str(self) % rhs
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 140, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 94, in gettext
    return _trans.gettext(message)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 355, in gettext
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 268, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "E:\coding\registrations\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 160, in __init__
    raise OSError('No translation files found for default language %s.' % settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
OSError: No translation files found for default language en-gb.
```

Any ideas on what may be happening here? As I said, everything was working well until a few days ago, then the gremlins got in.

Comment: It seems you're not using your virtual environment anymore; did you forget to activate it before running `manage.py`?

Comment: Hi. I am running the virtual environment - I just checked again and got the same error message.